# Replace image src and a href onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, image

I've got this little project where I want to swap an image for another, and display the new image in a lightbox.

The code below works as follows; when I click one of the small images, the image src of the large image is replaced with the src of the small image. However, when I click the large image, it still opens the default large image in my lightbox.

Is there any way I can make the hyperlink href get swapped the same way the image src is swapped? They need to get the same value.

The javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function switch1(div) {
        if (document.getElementById('one')) {
            var option=['one','two','three'];
            for(var i=0; i<option.length; i++) {
                obj=document.getElementById(option[i]);
                obj.style.display=(option[i]==div)? "block" : "none";
            }
        }
    }
    function switchImg(i){
        document.images["main-image"].src = i;
    }
</script>
```

The HTML/PHP:

```
<?php
    $image = 'main-image.jpg';
    $small_1 = 'small-image-1.jpg';
    $small_2 = 'small-image-2.jpg';
?>
<div id="holder">
<div class="large">
    <a href="<?php echo $image; ?>" rel="lightbox">
        <img id="main-image" src="<?php echo $image; ?>" />
    </a>
    <a class="original" onclick="switchImg('<?php echo $image; ?>')">Back to original image</a>
</div>
<div class="small">
    <a onclick="switchImg('<?php echo $small_1; ?>')">
        <img src="<?php echo $small_1; ?>" />
    </a>
    <a onclick="switchImg('<?php echo $small_2; ?>')">
        <img src="<?php echo $small_2; ?>" />
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would probably be easier for us to help on this problem if you give the rendered html, not the php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to change the href:

```
document.getElementById('YOUR_ID').href = 'abraCaDabraDotCom';
```

Comment: Thank you carter, that helped! I just added it to the switchImg function and it worked.