# Dynamically replace both 'src' and 'href' tags based on drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've set up an 'onchange' function for a select box that will dynamically change an image on the webpage based on which option is selected. This is so that users can select a room from a dropdown and then view the timetable for that room. However, the image shown was quite small, so I've implemented the lightbox program to allow users to click the image and make it larger.

I've adapted my onchange function to change the image that is shown initially, but when a user clicks the image, they are still shown the image declared in the `href`, as this value isn't changed by the onchange function.

I've tried a few methods that I thought would work, but to no avail. Does anyone have a solution for ensuring that the `href` value shown below **always** matches that shown later on in the `src` for the smaller image?

```html
<select required id="roomfield" name="roomfield" onchange="$('#imageToSwap').attr('src', this.options[this.selectedIndex].id); room()"> required>
 <option value=""></option>
 <option id="https://dat.ccits.org.uk/book/images/roomfield/c1.png" value="C1" roomname="test1">C1</option>
 <option id="https://dat.ccits.org.uk/book/images/roomfield/c2.png" value="C2" roomname="test2">C2</option>
 <option id="https://dat.ccits.org.uk/book/images/roomfield/c3.png" value="C3" roomname="test3">C3</option>
 <option id="https://dat.ccits.org.uk/book/images/roomfield/c8.png" value="C8" roomname="test4">C8</option>
 <option id="https://dat.ccits.org.uk/book/images/roomfield/c9.png" value="C9" roomname="test5">C9</option>
 <option id="https://dat.ccits.org.uk/book/images/roomfield/hall.png" value="Hall" roomname="testh">Hall</option>
 </select>

<a class="example-image-link" id="imageToSwap2" width="100%" href="https://dat.ccits.org.uk/book/images/roomfield/holder.png" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click the right half of the image to move forward.">
  <img class="example-image" id="imageToSwap" src="https://dat.ccits.org.uk/book/images/roomfield/holder.png" alt="" />
</a>
```

I have read [Replace image src and a href onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271935/replace-image-src-and-a-href-onclick) but can't seem to work out how to implement this solution into my existing code, with regards to the `document.getElementById('YOUR_ID').href = 'abraCaDabraDotCom';` part.

Comment: Why are you using full URLs for the `id` attribute? At the very least, use a data attribute for that, too. With that said: where's your code? I don't see any JS that's supposed to update the `<a href>` and `<img src>` when the `change` triggers for your selector. (and don't use `onchange`, use proper modern JS and have an `addEventListener('change')` on the JS side. Not HTML4.01 attributes.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm using the full URLs as the id as that's what the guide I followed told me to do. The only reason that they are full URLs, rather than just 'c1.png' is because they're hosted on a seperate site. The code for updating the images is contained within 'onChange', again, as the guide said to do. As for the other comments, I'll look into implementing those. Thank you

Comment: Then your guide is telling you to do _very_ questionable things. Don't use `id` attributes _at all_ unless you need to access those elements on the JS side. If not, don't set them. And you don't, you just need appropriately set `value` attributes that you copy over from select's onchange, using `event.target.value`. I strongly suggest finding  new tutorial that teaches modern HTML5+JS patterns, instead of something that mixes 1998 HTML 4.01 patterns with things that, given what `id` is meant to be used for, doesn't even make sense.

Comment: I've checked back through the notes I've made during development. The guide did state to use the 'value' tag. However, I had to modify and adapt this as I already have another function that looks to the ID tag of each drop down option.

Comment: Which should be trivial to change to using the `value` property instead and do the right thing. Do your future self, and possibly anyone who has to work with your code later, a favour: take that extra bit of time now that you still know where to look, to fix the mistakes, so you or someone else doesn't spend much more time later to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should find the parent of image which is `a` container in example and replace corresponding href with the selected value via `$('#imageToSwap').parent().attr('href', this.options[this.selectedIndex].id)` as follows:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select required id="roomfield" name="roomfield" onchange="$('#imageToSwap').parent().attr('href', this.options[this.selectedIndex].id);$('#imageToSwap').attr('src', this.options[this.selectedIndex].id); room()"> required>
 <option value=""></option>
 <option id="https://dat.ccits.org.uk/book/images/roomfield/c1.png" value="C1" roomname="test1">C1</option>
 <option id="https://dat.ccits.org.uk/book/images/roomfield/c2.png" value="C2" roomname="test2">C2</option>
 <option id="https://dat.ccits.org.uk/book/images/roomfield/c3.png" value="C3" roomname="test3">C3</option>
 <option id="https://dat.ccits.org.uk/book/images/roomfield/c8.png" value="C8" roomname="test4">C8</option>
 <option id="https://dat.ccits.org.uk/book/images/roomfield/c9.png" value="C9" roomname="test5">C9</option>
 <option id="https://dat.ccits.org.uk/book/images/roomfield/hall.png" value="Hall" roomname="testh">Hall</option>
 </select>

</br>
</br>
<a class="example-image-link" id="imageToSwap2" width="100%" href="https://dat.ccits.org.uk/book/images/roomfield/holder.png" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click the right half of the image to move forward."><img class="example-image" id="imageToSwap" src="https://dat.ccits.org.uk/book/images/roomfield/holder.png" alt="" /></a>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I've marked this as the answer as it was the simplest solution to my problem. Other suggestions may have also worked, but this one was the easiest to implement at this time. I did have to remove the '>' just before the end 'required' attribute, however.

Answer (score 0):

By putting all the logic into the `onchange` property the code is hard to read and hard to change. This can be fixed by abstracting it to a separate script section. Another possible change is the use of the dataset property: (`data-*`) to store additional data such as the url of an option

```js
const imageToSwap = document.querySelector('#imageToSwap');
const lightboxLink = document.querySelector('#imageToSwap2')

document.querySelector('#roomfield').addEventListener('change', e => {
  const elem = e.currentTarget;
  const selectedUrl = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].dataset.url;
 imageToSwap.setAttribute('src', selectedUrl)
  lightboxLink.setAttribute('href', selectedUrl)
})
```

```html
<select required id="roomfield" name="roomfield" required>
 <option value=""></option>
 <option data-url="https://dat.ccits.org.uk/book/images/roomfield/c1.png" value="C1" roomname="test1">C1</option>
 <option data-url="https://dat.ccits.org.uk/book/images/roomfield/c2.png" value="C2" roomname="test2">C2</option>
 <option data-url="https://dat.ccits.org.uk/book/images/roomfield/c3.png" value="C3" roomname="test3">C3</option>
 <option data-url="https://dat.ccits.org.uk/book/images/roomfield/c8.png" value="C8" roomname="test4">C8</option>
 <option data-url="https://dat.ccits.org.uk/book/images/roomfield/c9.png" value="C9" roomname="test5">C9</option>
 <option data-url="https://dat.ccits.org.uk/book/images/roomfield/hall.png" value="Hall" roomname="testh">Hall</option>
 </select>

<br />
<br/>
<a class="example-image-link" id="imageToSwap2" width="100%" href="https://dat.ccits.org.uk/book/images/roomfield/holder.png" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click the right half of the image to move forward."><img class="example-image" id="imageToSwap" src="https://dat.ccits.org.uk/book/images/roomfield/holder.png" alt="" /></a>
```